# Convert Text to datetime in MS Excel

Tags: excel, datetime

I am trying to convert form DateTime value string such as "Feb 13, 2015 20:03:36:820" to DateTime values in Microsoft Excel. I know I can convert from a string such as '01/12/2015' to Date. But I want both date and time parts. 
Is there anyway we can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your data in **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,12))
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,14,8))
```

Then give **B1** a *Date* format and give **C1** a *Time* format.

[image]

**EDIT#1**

To use a **Single** cell the formula would be:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,12)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,14,8))
```

[image]

Comment: so, it looks like we have to split date and time into separate cells.

Comment: @ShweKhine ...........Actually you can combine the two formulas into a single *(if you are careful)*